# DSE Loading Data using Bulk Loader

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Currently, I have successfully installed the necessary nodes and datacenters through the usage of the OpsCenter.

I have also generated the necessary table and Keyspace using Cassandra through DataStax Studio

**KeySpace Generated**

```
CREATE KEYSPACE graph_tables WITH REPLICATION = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1};
```

**Table Generated**

```
CREATE TABLE people_node (id text, name text, age int, location 'PointType', gender text, dob timestamp, PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

**Sample Data**

```
id, name , age, location, gender, dob
0,  Betsy, 15 , 10 15   , F     , 1997-09-21T12:55:54
```

Assuming we have a node_1 with the IP Address 1.1.1.1 and second node called node_2 with the IP Address 2.2.2.2. These will be the two nodes that the OpsCenter have installed Cassandra on

From here I attempted to insert the necessary data using dsbulk

```
dsbulk load -url ./people_node_csv -k graph_tables -t people_node -h '1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2 ' -header true
```

However, this results in an error stating "Operation Load_..... failed: Authentication error on host /1.1.1.1:9042: Host /1.1.1.1:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator found in Cluster Configurations". I attempted to resolve this by adding in "driver.ssl.keystone.password = cassandra" as shown in the [Document](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/getStartedDsbulk.html). But the error still persist. Any advise on solving this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: also, please take into account that `PointType` takes input formatter as `POINT(x y)` where `x` is longitude, and `y` is lattitude...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide following settings as described in [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/securityOptions.html):

- `-u` - to specify user name
- `-p` - to specify password
- `--driver.auth.provider DsePlainTextAuthProvider` - to select corresponding authentication provider.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @Alex Ott. I would also like to clarify on how gremlin will work with cassandra. The moment data is loaded into cassandra, gremlin will be able to sense this data and all I need to do it to create the schema for each table in cassandra specifying which is the node and which is the edge? Or is is more advisable to create the schema in gremlin first?

Comment: Unfortunately DSBulk doesn't support loading of the data into DSE Graph yet. For this task you can either user DSE Graph Loader (https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/dgl/graphloaderTOC.html), or DSE GraphFrames (https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/graphAnalytics/dseGraphFrameImport.html, https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/dse-graph-frame) - in both cases you'll need to create a graph via gremlin first.

Comment: this happens as DSE needs to insert data into multiple tables when you update verrices, add edges, etc.

Comment: I see, I have actually started using graph loader and encountered an error in loading the data due to timestamp formatting `2014-10-18T13:08:16` as it recognizes it as a string. I looked around and found a post stating `Also regarding TimeStamp should be a number value for it to be successfully loaded via DSE Graphloader.`. Hence, I would like to know how should the timestamp be formatted for it to load properly into DSE? At the same time I assume that Point(..) is the correct format for loading in data through the graph loader. @Alex Ott

Comment: Point format should be the same. Regarding timestamp  - I think that the problem is that it doesn't include time zone component